# Does symmetric cryptography data leak compromise key?

Tags: cryptography

Let's assume an attacker obtains the following data:

- An encrypted message
- A decrypted message and he is 100% sure that this decrypted message content is the same as the encrypted message.

Is this attacker able to reproduce key and/or compromise other messages encrypted with the same key?

Comment: Look up "known plaintext attacks"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: The attacker can always be assumed to have a copy of the plaintext, as Blorgbeard implies.  For example, the Ruritanian embassy recieves a 5K encrypted radio message.  A day later the Ruritanian Ambassador hands your Foreign Minister a 5K diplomatic note.  You now have both the cyphertext from the intercepted radio transmission and the plaintext from the diplomatic note.  All good ciphers can resist a known plaintext attack.